# Hide Selection of Text From Archive, but Show on Single Posts

Tags: shortcode, archives, single

I'm looking for a shortcode similar to this:

```
[hidetext]some text to hide[/hidetext]
```

Then what will happen is that the the tag will hide the text from any page that isn't the Single Post page. Only on the Single Post Page will the `[hidetext]` show. How can I do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add_shortcode( 'hidetext', 'my_hidetext_shortcode' );
function my_hidetext_shortcode( $atts, $content = '' ) {
    if( is_single() )
        return $content;
    else
        return;
}
```

Docs: [`add_shortcode()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode), [`is_single()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single)

Solution is untested.

Answer (score 2):

A slight modification on the function above. You'll want to use `is_singular('post')` instead, unless you also want to target other areas

```
add_shortcode( 'hidetext', 'rkv_hidetext_shortcode' );

function rkv_hidetext_shortcode( $atts, $content = null) {
    if( is_singular('post') )
        return $content;
    else
        return;
}
```

tested and works.